# 14.04 recognizes Linksys WPC54G, but is not listed

Tags: wireless

I used the **Additional Drivers** feature to enable the **Broadcom drivers**. I rebooted, but I am still unable to use my wireless card. I assumed it would just appear in the list of devices in the networking menu at the top of the screen, but it does not. I feel like I am close because it does recognize the device and says it's using the correct driver. What am I missing?

boo@bit-master:~$ lspcmcia

boo@bit-master:~$

Comment: try with installing drivers containing packages: `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: @BillGates There's no reason to install `build-essential` or `libssl-dev`...

Comment: There are about six different versions of this device, many using differing chipsets and not all are Broadcom. Any attempt to fix your install without identifying your exact device is fruitless. Please run from a terminal: lspcmcia ident and edit your question to add the result.